# String removal and retainment for particular conditions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Suppose if have a string **M004US8060UfG**
If first four character is **M004** then I have to remove **M004** and retain US8060UfG
if last character is zero i.e  **M004US8060Uf0** then remove the last zero and retain only  **US8060Uf**

Comment: As you are rather new here (Btw: Welcome!) please allow me one hint: If this question is solved, it would be kind, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are  - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(s VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('M004US8060UfG'),('M004US8060Uf0'),('SomeOther')

SELECT Step2
FROM @t AS t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE WHEN LEFT(t.s,4)='M004' THEN SUBSTRING(t.s,5,9999) ELSE t.s END AS Step1 ) AS A
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE WHEN RIGHT(Step1,1)='0' THEN LEFT(Step1,LEN(Step1)-1) ELSE Step1 END AS Step2) AS B
```

The result

```
US8060UfG
US8060Uf
SomeOther
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a simple case would do  (stole Shnugo's table)

Note: This assumes only one trailing zero will be removed

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(s VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('M004US8060UfG'),('M004US8060Uf0'),('SomeOther'),('Trailing0')

Select *
      ,NewValue = case when S like 'M004%0' then substring(S,5,len(S)-5) 
                       when S like 'M004%'  then substring(S,5,len(S)) 
                       when S like '%0'     then substring(S,1,len(S)-1)
                       else S end
 From  @t
```

**Returns**

```
s               NewValue
--------------  -----------
M004US8060UfG   US8060UfG
M004US8060Uf0   US8060Uf
SomeOther       SomeOther
Trailing0       Trailing
```